# "Delay Relay" or better "Ignore Relay" advice

Tags: voltage, relay, timer, delay

I have an inherited project that is baffling me. (I am NOT an EE.)

TL;DR: need to ignore the signal voltage for the first 45 seconds (upon power-up), then allows all signal voltage there after.

**Problem:** Upon power up, unit POST sends a one-time 5 V signal on pin #9, then nothing until power cycled again. HOWEVER, during normal operation pin #9 is used to trigger a signal to a relay beginning a large "emergency procedure" alarm.

This trigger signal is the EXACT same voltage and duration as the signal from the unit POST.

**Solve** I need a circuit that upon powering up, ignores any signal voltage for 45 seconds. After 45 seconds, any signal received is allowed to trigger the Emergency procedure relay.

**I have tried**

1. Designing a small PCB with a Capacitor as the "gate", don't see that working
2. All 7 modes of this little bad boy, mode 5 works but must be reset every 9,999 minutes ([Amazon DROK timer link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07DFT2WDS)).
   [image: Image of Amazon DROK timer]
3. Crying in the corner

Comment: Pin 9 of _what?_

Comment: We would need to know something more about this device, all we know is it outputs a 5V signal on power up and on an alarm, but we don't know how power up is initiated or if there's any way to tell when power up occurs that can be differentiated from an alarm occurring.

Comment: How critical is the 45-second delay duration?  Is 46 seconds acceptable?  40?  A good time delay relay (not from Amazon) *could* work, but the signal is probably such low current that you'd need a SSR or gold-contact model.

Comment: Why don't you just move the emergency procedure alarm to a different pin??? Why co-locate/conflate two distinct functions like that?

Comment: Sounds like you want an [On-Delay Relay](https://www.google.com/search?q=on-delay+relay).

Comment: @JYelton Sorry didn't think the device mattered... it is a mobile radio

Comment: @GodJihyo there is no way to differentiate power up vs alarm besides timing. The alarm is triggered by a human for an emergency

Comment: @vir Time isn't super critical just needs to ignore between 45s and 60s

Comment: @periblepsis Oh bud, if I could I would! However, this is an integration error from another vendor because our old engineer didn't realize there was a signal upon POST.

Comment: @brhans this might just work... I will look into it. Hopefully, it doesn't just delay my current issue longer...

Comment: @rag-Gnar If you can’t differentiate power up from an alarm how can you know when to start the timer?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how.

[image]

'K1' is an off-the-shelf, 'on delay' timer.

It delays power to the 'emergency procedure alarm' by 45".

The 'power-up' pulse from 'POST' is thereby ignored.

Comment: Thanks! (Sorry I am too new to the site to upvote your answer)

Comment: Anytime and no problem!